# Can 1,1,1,1 ....be considered as a Harmonic Progression?

Tags: sequences-and-series

An harmonic progression is the reciprocal of an Arithmetic Progression and since $1,1,1$ is an Arithmetic Progression then $1,1,1\cdots $ should be an harmonic progression too but [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:First_members_of_harmonic_sequence.svg) graph on wikipedia portrays an another thing.

Comment: No doubt @nicomezi, but the words Harmonic (or sometimes harmonical) Progression mean exactly what the question says, see any decent book on elementary algebra. The wiki article is about the harmonic sequence.

Comment: Well ok, thank you for the information. It seems it was me having a problem with this terminology. @ancientmathematician

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The graph you've linked shows the behavior of the most famous harmonic sequence, $a_n = 1/n$; its terms are the reciprocal of the arithmetic progression $1,2,3, \ldots$.

Based on your definition, then yes, the constant sequence of $1$s is a harmonic progression as well, but it's hardly an interesting one. Different arithmetic progressions will produce different harmonic progressions.

Comment: Is my definition of an Harmnonic Progression,mathematically correct? Thanks@christopher

Comment: @Rasputin Not all definitions are universally agreed upon. However, a quick look at Wikipedia seems to indicate that harmonic progressions as taking reciprocals of terms of an arithmetic sequence is a well-known definition.